# Get the ID of clicked element and use it as $(this)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, this

I need to be able to click an element, get the ID of that element and use it on another function. How can I do it as It is not working using `$(this)`. This is what I have so far:

```js
$("#pills-ficha").on("click", closePillsOnClick);

function closePillsOnClick() {
  var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
  var clickedIdChild = $(this).html($(this).html().split("By:").join(""));

  if ($(clickedId).hasClass("active")) {
    $(clickedId).removeClass("active show");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(clickedIdChild).removeClass("active show").css("display", "none");
  } else {
    $(clickedIdChild).css("display", "block");
    $(clickedIdChild).siblings().css("display", "none");
  }
}
```

/* edit */

I'll add the markup:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center">
                        <ul id="examples" class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start" role="tablist">
                            <span class="text-blue font-weight-medium">EJEMPLOS:</span>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="pills-ficha-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-ficha" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-ficha" aria-selected="false">Ficha</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="pills-candidato-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-candidato" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-candidato" aria-selected="false">Mail candidato</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="pills-empresa-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-empresa" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-empresa" aria-selected="false">Mail empresa</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 text-center tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-ficha" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-ficha-tab">
                    <img src="img/gold/gold-ejemplo-ficha.jpg" alt="Ejemplo de ficha">
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-candidato" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-candidato-tab">
                    <img src="img/gold/gold-ejemplo-candidato.jpg" alt="Ejemplo de mail al candidato">
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-empresa" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-empresa-tab">
                    <img src="img/gold/gold-ejemplo-empresa.jpg" alt="Ejemplo de mail a la empresa">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Firsty, what you have will retrieve the `id`. If it doesn't for you, check the console for errors. Secondly, you don't need to get the `id` at all as you can just use `$(this)` within the function to reference the element anyway

Comment: please add your html to question to be clear

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n40zxphw/ - seems to be working fine in terms of getting the id. What exact problem are you facing? (It's hard for me to verify the rest of it since we don't know the structure of your HTML. Also we don't know precisely what is giving you a problem anyway - the demo proves it's not the ID, so presumably there's something else the matter. Try to describe your issue more specifically)

Comment: BTW `$(clickedId).hasClass("active")` won't work (because "clickedId" will be "pills-ficha" without the "#", and jQuery will need the "#". But it's unnecessary anyway because you can just do `$(this).hasClass("active")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my original question was this part:

```
var clickedIdChild = $(this).html($(this).html().split("By:").join(""));
```

It had to be:

```
var clickedIdChild = clickedId.split(":By").join("");
```

Also adding:

$("#"+clickedIdChild) as a selector.

Then this works as expected:

```
function closePillsOnClick(e){

    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
    var clickedIdChild = clickedId.split("-tab").join("");

    if( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
        $(this).removeClass("active show");
      e.stopPropagation();
        $("#"+clickedIdChild).removeClass("active show").css("display", "none");  

    } else {
        $("#"+clickedIdChild).css("display", "block"); 
        $("#"+clickedIdChild).siblings().css("display", "none");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your logic is because `attr('id')` is returning you back `pills-ficha`, which in itself is not a valid selector. You would need to append `#` to it for it to work.

*However* this is a flawed approach. You already have the reference to the element itself through the `this` keyword. Creating a reference to that element to get its `id` to then get another reference to the same element by that `id` is entirely pointless.

As such, you can simplify the logic like this:

```js
$("#pills-ficha").on("click", closePillsOnClick);

function closePillsOnClick() {
  var $clicked = $(this);
  var clickedIdChild = $clicked.html($clicked.html().split("By:").join(""));

  if ($clicked.hasClass("active")) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $clicked.removeClass("active show");
    $(clickedIdChild).removeClass("active show").hide();
  } else {
    $(clickedIdChild).show().siblings().hide()
  }
}
```

It's likely you can do the same with the `clickedIdChild` reference, but your HTML doesn't show enough information for me to give you an example of how to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

OK let's clarify this. `var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");` will return ID in the form `fakeId`. Next you have a jQuery with with the ID (`$(clickedId)`) which will be `$('fakeId')` in my example. ID selector needs to start with `#` so you have to add it. So valid code will be `$('#' + clickedId)`. More here:

- http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/attr

Cheers.

Comment: true but they could just use `$(this)` directly. Getting the ID out, and then using it as a new selector is totally redundant.

Comment: You are right, but the question was to use the ID as selector

Comment: ok but sometimes the correct answer is actually "you don't need to do that." It's often referred to as an "X-Y problem".